# Using gprof with LULESH benchmark

Tags: c++, gcc, makefile, gprof

I've been trying to compile and run LULESH benchmark

https://codesign.llnl.gov/lulesh.php

https://codesign.llnl.gov/lulesh/lulesh2.0.3.tgz

with gprof but I always get a segmentation fault. I updated these instructions in the Makefile:

```
CXXFLAGS = -g -pg -O3 -I. -Wall 

LDFLAGS = -g -pg -O3

[andrestoga@n01 lulesh2.0.3]$ mpirun -np 8 ./lulesh2.0 -s 16 -p -i 10
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
mpirun noticed that process rank 2 with PID 30557 on node n01 exited on signal 11 (Segmentation fault).
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

In the webpage of gprof says the following:

> If you are running the program on a system which supports shared
>   libraries you may run into problems with the profiling support code in
>   a shared library being called before that library has been fully
>   initialised. This is usually detected by the program encountering a
>   segmentation fault as soon as it is run. The solution is to link
>   against a static version of the library containing the profiling
>   support code, which for gcc users can be done via the `-static' or`
>   -static-libgcc' command line option. For example:
>
> ```
>  gcc -g -pg -static-libgcc myprog.c utils.c -o myprog
> ```

I added the -static command line option and I also got segmentation fault.

I found a pdf where they profiled LULESH by updating the Makefile by adding the command line option -pg. Although they didn't say the changes they made.

http://periscope.in.tum.de/releases/latest/pdf/PTF_Best_Practices_Guide.pdf

Page 11

Could someone help me out please?

Best,

Comment: It would probably help if you posted a stacktrace.

Comment: Thanks! How I can generate a stacktrace?

Comment: Make sure your `ulimit` is set correctly (e.g. `ulimit -c unlimited`), and run `gdb prog core`, then `where`.

Comment: Sorry but I don't have experience using ulimit or gdb. In what part do I set ulimit?

Comment: I run in the terminal "ulimit -c unlimited" then I run my program and it generates these files: core.6493  core.6495 core.6494  core.6496. Then I run "gdb prog core" and I got "prog: No such file or directory.
/home/andrestoga/LULESH/lulesh2.0.3/core: No such file or directory." then "where" and I got "(gdb) where
No stack."

Comment: Try running `gdb $prog $core` (where `$prog` is your program and `$core` is your core file).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95391/discussion-between-user702475-and-jason).

Answer (score 0):

Make sure all libraries are loaded:

1. openmpi (which you have done already)
2. gcc

You can try with parameters that will allow you to identify if the problem is your machine in terms of resources. if the machine does not support such number of processes see how many processes (MPI or not MPI) it supports by looking at the architecture topology. This will allow you to identify what is the correct amount of jobs/processes you can launch into the system.

Very quick run:

> mpirun -np 1 ./lulesh2.0 -s 1 -p -i 1

```
Running problem size 1^3 per domain until completion
Num processors: 1
Num threads: 2
Total number of elements: 1

To run other sizes, use -s <integer>.
To run a fixed number of iterations, use -i <integer>.
To run a more or less balanced region set, use -b <integer>.
To change the relative costs of regions, use -c <integer>.
To print out progress, use -p
To write an output file for VisIt, use -v
See help (-h) for more options

cycle = 1, time = 1.000000e-02, dt=1.000000e-02
Run completed:  
 Problem size        =  1 
 MPI tasks           =  1 
 Iteration count     =  1 
 Final Origin Energy = 4.333329e+02 
Testing Plane 0 of Energy Array on rank 0:
    MaxAbsDiff   = 0.000000e+00
    TotalAbsDiff = 0.000000e+00
    MaxRelDiff   = 0.000000e+00


Elapsed time         =       0.00 (s)
Grind time (us/z/c)  =        518 (per dom)  (       518 overall)
FOM                  =  1.9305019 (z/s)
```